# How to filter Google map

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, filter

I m working with google map and i would like to hide if it's possible the restaurant and hotel from my map.
So my question is how to eliminate or apply a filter  to hide restaurant and hotels points in google map api.

Thank you for all.
edit.

```
<script>
  function writeAddressName(latLng) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
      "location": latLng
    },
    function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
        document.getElementById("address").innerHTML = results[0].formatted_address;
      else
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML += "Unable to retrieve your address" + "<br />";
    });
  }


  function geolocationSuccess(position) {
    var userLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    writeAddressName(userLatLng);

   $(document).ready(function(){
var styles = [
    {
        stylers: [
            { hue: "#00ffe6" },
            { saturation: -20 }
        ]
    },{
        featureType: "road",
        elementType: "geometry",
        stylers: [
            { lightness: 100 },
            { visibility: "simplified" }
        ]
    },{
        featureType: "road",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [
            { visibility: "off" }
        ]
    }
];

var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, {name: "Styled Map"});

// display map
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: userLatLng ,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,'map_style']
    }
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

 map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
 map.setMapTypeId('map_style', styledMap);
});
    // marker
    new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map_style,
      position: userLatLng
    });
```

Comment: are you just rendering the map or making api calls?

Comment: mmh i don't know your question i m just making a map javascript using google map api to launch the map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You map styles to hide certain elements on the road map for example
The API hint you are looking for is google.maps.MapTypeStyle: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#MapTypeStyle

Examples of how to use it can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling

In your case the style would look somehow like this:

```
{
featureType: "poi.business",
elementType: "labels",
stylers: [
  { visibility: "off" }
]
}
```

:edit:
working example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/Elak/ndjC8/7/

```
    var styles = [
    {
        stylers: [
            { hue: "#00ffe6" },
            { saturation: -20 }
        ]
    },{
        featureType: "road",
        elementType: "geometry",
        stylers: [
            { lightness: 100 },
            { visibility: "simplified" }
        ]
    },{
        featureType: "road",
        elementType: "labels",
        stylers: [
            { visibility: "off" }
        ]
    }
];

// Create a new StyledMapType object, passing it the array of styles,
// as well as the name to be displayed on the map type control.
var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(styles, {name: "Styled Map"});

// Dessin de la map
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.6468, 37.581),
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'map_style']
    }
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

//Associate the styled map with the MapTypeId and set it to display.
map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
map.setMapTypeId('map_style');
```

Comment: Thank for your help Ela but i didn't succeed i must to admit that i m a beginner with javascript and that i use it just punctually

Comment: you really have to read through the documentation of how to set this up. There is a little bit more code involved.
Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Elak/ndjC8/7/

Comment: Ok thank you help Ela i have some troubleshooting to display the map i don't know why. I tried all this afternoon to understand but it didn't come. I need to work more on that.

Comment: Did you see the example on jsfiddle? Is it running for you?
If that answers your question also please mark this as answered and put a new question if you have other issues with google map ;)
Thanks

Comment: I saw the example and i ve edited my code and it didn't work =/

Comment: this means you basically did something wrong
Here is the link to the example, please look in the source code of the page (right click->source code), it contains only what it needs to run google and jquery... and the script I posted
http://fiddle.jshell.net/Elak/ndjC8/7/show/

Comment: it's okay thank you for your help now i have to integrate this styled map into my function localisation isn't it ?